# powershell extract from the loop

Tags: powershell

I have below script

```
Switch -Wildcard ("$($group)$($action)") {
    "Citrix*" {$GroupC = ("#GG-$CC--Citrix1","#GG-$CC-Citrix2-","#GG-$CC-Citrix3")}
}

If ($group -eq "Citrix"){
    $Response = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $DateInFuture = Read-Host "How long user will be active (: in Days) "
    ForEach ($GroupXc in $GroupC) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Credential $cred -Identity $GroupXc -Members $User.samaccountname -Verbose
    }
}
```

I want to save results in .csv with variables $DateInFuture groupXc  credentials
I am not sure how should i extract **GroupXc** outside the loop

any easy method ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of context here but this should get you started.  You need to populate an array or arraylist with objects.  That makes it very easy to export to a csv file.

Example:

```
    Switch -Wildcard ("$($group)$($action)") {
        "Citrix*" {$GroupC = ("#GG-$CC--Citrix1","#GG-$CC-Citrix2-","#GG-$CC-Citrix3")}
    }
    $OutputFile = C:\Temp\SomeOutput.csv # Obviously you should change this...
    $Response = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    If ($group -eq "Citrix")
    {
        $DateInFuture = Read-Host "How long user will be active (: in Days) "

        ForEach ($GroupXc in $GroupC)
        { # Start loop
            $Response.Add( 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                DateInFuture = $DateInFuture
                GroupXc      = $GroupXc
                Credentials  = $Credentials
            } ) 

        Add-ADGroupMember -Credential $cred -Identity $GroupXc -Members $User.samaccountname -Verbose
        } # End loop
    }

$Response | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Obviously you'd have to play around with how & where you're populated the objects.  You've got to match it to your needs.  This is just an example...